# Create shaped node with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a node with the same shape as the box in the upper left having text "Suppliers" in the image below?

[image]

Besides, does there exist any tikz package with symbols like cars/carts/trucks/ship or something like that? I guess I have once seen these but I can't find them now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\newcommand` that draws a node (the text) but without border. Then you will draw a path using the nodes anchors and some extra calculations.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\newcommand{\industry}[2]{
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm] (main) at (#1) {#2};
    \draw (main.south west) -- (main.south east) -- (main.north east) --++
     (0,5mm) --++ (-1cm,-5mm) --++ (0,5mm) --++ (-1cm,-5mm) --++ (0,5mm) -- (main.north west) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\industry{0,0}{Suppliers}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use it inside a tikzpicture rather than creating a new tikzpicture every time I use the command? With a pic or something. I just need to position other nodes relative to this node, so I am not sure if I can use a pic for this

Comment: @Jamgreen Sure, you can remove that environment if you already use it in the document. I changed the answer.